# Modifying polygon attribute interactively on web map for public interaction

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, rendering, web, redistricting

I am looking for examples or ideas on how to create a web map using esri javascript api for redistricting purposes. On the web map, it would show the school boundaries in smaller sections (similar to census tracts) and would allow the user to interactively change the areas to create a new/modified boundary by clicking on the polygon and selecting another area using a dropdown list. It would then ask the user to print and/or email the new map to us for review. This map is the only thing I was able to find that is somewhat similar to what I am looking for: http://redistricting.greatergreaterwashington.org/

I thought about using the renderer unique value to separate my boundaries ([ArcGIS API for JavaScript Sandbox](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=renderer_unique_value)) but I have not been able to find a way for a user to interactively be able to change the attribute to a different category.

Is this a possible task and does anyone have any examples I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my own question/concern. If anyone is interested or would like to see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LjzzLeoe/

It was a combination of using the [ESRI Renderer Unique Value](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/renderer_unique_value.html) and [Attribute Inspector](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/ed_attribute_inspector.html). You will need delete this section from the attribute inspector code so that any changes on the attributes do not get permanently saved and the next user can see the default map with its properties.

```
     attInspector.on("next", function(evt) {
        updateFeature = evt.feature;
        console.log("Next " + updateFeature.attributes.OBJECTID);
      });

      attInspector.on("delete", function(evt) {
        evt.feature.getLayer().applyEdits(null, null, [evt.feature]);
        map.infoWindow.hide();
      });
```

Comment: Can you expand on what the solution was? If that link ever breaks, your "answer" will no longer be helpful to others in a similar situation.